# Executar SELECT dentro de um CASE

Tags: php, sql

Estou utilizando o `php` para fazer um `SELECT` do banco de dados, porém preciso que o `select` verifique se um dos campos foi preenchido e, se sim, executar um novo `SELECT` de outra tabela.

Basicamente a ideia é que tenho uma tabela de cupons:

```
tabela: cadastro_cupom
id | nome_cupom | valor_cupom | id_cliente
```

Quando o campo `id_cliente` for preenchido, eu preciso pegar o nome dele de outra tabela:

```
tabela: cadastro_cliente
id | nome_cliente | idade_cliente | etc...
```

No momento estou usando esse SQL:

```
SELECT id, nome_cupom, valor_cupom, id_cliente
FROM cadastro_cupom
    CASE WHEN id_cliente IS NOT NULL THEN
        SELECT b.nome_cliente
        FROM cadastro_cupom a, cadastro_cliente b
        WHERE a.id_cliente = b.id
    END
```

Porém eu não estou conseguindo obter os resultados e também não me aparece nenhum erro.

Comment: Usar o `left join` tal como `SELECT a.*, b.* FROM cadastro_cupom a LEFT JOIN cadastro_cliente b ON a.id_cliente = b.id` não resolveria ?

Comment: @WilliamNovak parece que resolveu sim. Sou novo em SQL e PHP então não sabia dessa função.. Se puder elaborar uma resposta abordando melhor o assunto, agradeceria :)

Answer (score 1):

A pergunta já tem uma resposta nos comentários, mas fica aqui uma resposta caso alguém se depare com a mesma questão no futuro

```
SELECT Cup.id, 
       Cup.nome_cupom, 
       Cup.valor_cupom, 
       Cli.id_cliente
FROM cadastro_cupom Cup
LEFT JOIN cadastro_cliente Cli
  ON Cli.id = Cup.id_cliente
```

Esta query irá retornar para todos os cupões, o id do respectivo cliente, caso este exista. No caso do cliente não estiver preenchido a query lista apenas os detalhes do cupão.

Caso pretendas listar apenas os cupões para os quais existe um cliente associado, substitui o `LEFT JOIN` por um `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você quer recuperar o nome do cliente. As respostas acima já te fornecem um caminho para o que você precisa.
De qualquer forma vou apenas acrescentar uma possibilidade supondo `id_cliente` ser um índice em suas entidades:

```
SELECT id, nome_cupom, valor_cupom, id_cliente, 
     (SELECT nome_cliente FROM cadastro_cliente c 
       WHERE c.id_cliente = a.id_cliente) nome_cliente 
 FROM cadastro_cupom 
WHERE id_cliente is NOT NULL -- se quiser apenas cupons com clientes.
;
```

Sugiro verificar o custo desta query e das demais.